# Can't rename volume group in linux that had hyphens/dashes in name

Tags: bash, rename, lvm

I made a typo when I created an LVM group under Centos 6.4. I'm trying to rename using the syntax `vgrename /dev/mapper/oldVG /dev/mapper/newVG`. However, both the old and new VGs have hyphens in the name: `/dev/mapper/BACKUP-StoreVG` and `/dev/mapper/StoreVG-BackupLV`, respectively.

I get the error message:

`New volume group name "StoreVG/BackupLV" is invalid`

I've tried escaping with `\`, putting the volumes in single and double quotes. Also tried a `--` after the command `vgrename`. If I try to rename to something without a hyphen (i.e. `StoreVGBackupLV`) it complains about the old name instead: `Volume group name BACKUP/StoreVG has invalid characters`.

The LVM is unmounted. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The `/dev/mapper` path always has an hyphen because it has two components, the vg name and the lv name.  Do this:

```
lvrename /dev/mapper/VGName-LVName NewLVName
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP is trying to rename the VG, not the LV, so `lvrename` won't cut it.

The problem is that you're trying to reference the end path of the LV (`/dev/mapper/vgname-lvname`) whereas you have to use the `/dev/vgname/lvname` format for `vgrename`. That is to say, you should be trying:

```
vgrename /dev/vgname-old /dev/vgname-new
```

That just worked for me, with hyphens and all.